# Batch file to delete images

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that will delete images with specific names. The images will have names such as

house-200x300.jpg
car-125x250.jpg

So what I need ideally is a regular expression to target files which end in -(Num1)x(Num2).jpg

Also, the images are in various folders and sub folders so I need to do this recursively from the parent folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using powershell? 
Regular expressions in batch files get very bad very fast as the syntax is limited. 
My experience is limited, so there may very well be a better solution than this:

```dos
@echo off
FOR /F "delims=?" %%i IN ('dir /B /S ^| findstr /R "[^\.]*[0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg"') DO (
del /s "%%i" >nul 2>&1
)
```

I'm redirecting the output as I *think* that `FOR` starts to get confused about the output of `del`.

Answer (score 0):

```
del /S *-???x???.jpg
```

Perhaps you may want to change `del` by `dir /B` command at first just to check that there is not any file that have not the specified file name format, but that will be selected by this wild-card.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.jpg" ^|findstr /i /e /r /c:"-[0-9][0-9]*x[0-9][0-9]*\.jpg"'
  ) DO (
 ECHO DEL "%%a"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

This should do the job - targeting only those filenames ending with `-numXnum.jpg`

You'd need to set your own `sourcedir`

The required DEL commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO DEL` to `DEL` to actually delete the files.